# Can I move all logic in Load to PreRender?

Tags: asp.net

We have a user control and in the user control there are many sub-controls.

The user control reads database and set visibility and other properties of its sub-controls.

My friend puts most of the logic in PreRender event and says visibility is usually set in PreRender. Is this true?

What is the best practice of choosing Load and PreRender? What problems will I have if I write all logic in PreRender?

I copy some statements from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx, so you know I've read them a hundred times.

> Use the OnLoad event method to set properties in controls and to
>   establish database connections.

**Are there any problems if I establish database connections in PreRender?**

> PreRender: Use the event to make final changes to the contents of the
>   page or its controls before the rendering stage begins.

**Why can't I use the last change to do everything rather than final minor modification?**

Comment: Go through this MSDN thread on ASP.NET page life cycle. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: @PrashanthThurairatnam Yeah, of course. PreRender: Use the event to make final changes to the contents of the page. Why can't I use the last change to do everything?

Comment: What do you mean by everything?

Comment: everything that was done in Load event